# spring boot creating record in one microservice and calling other microsrvice created record not found in databse

Tags: spring-boot

spring boot  creating  record in one microservice and calling  other microsrvice  created record not found in databse

how to fix this i am using same database in all microservice and i am using the resttemplate calls to communicate  and transactional annotation also used .Also save and flush is used

Comment: Could you provide use some code?
Does the insert operation runs in a transaction?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So which one is it? transactional annotation or save and flush? Those 2 should be mutually exclusive. I will give an answer assuming that you use declarative transaction management (transactional annotation). If a method is marked as transactional all changes are committed once the method execution is finished. So, if you called another microservice from your method it means that your changes were not committed to DB yet and your other microservice opens a separate transaction and will NOT see the changes that were not committed yet in your first transaction. There are ways to configure DB so that other transactions can see uncommitted changes by other transactions, but I wouldn't recommend doing so unless you have a really compelling reason for this and truly understand what all the consequences of such configuration mean. As for how to solve your issue - you probably need a better design of your dataflow.